# Find the limit definition of derivative for the function $f(x)=\sqrt{7x+6}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Use the limit definition of derivative to find $f'(x)$ for the function $f(x)=\sqrt{7x+6}$

I'm stuck on this problem since I've never had a problem with square roots.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
f'(x)=&\,\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x)}{\varepsilon}=\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{\sqrt{7x+6+7\varepsilon}-\sqrt{7x+6}}{\varepsilon}\\
=&\,\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{\sqrt{7x+6+7\varepsilon}-\sqrt{7x+6}}{\varepsilon}\times\frac{\sqrt{7x+6+7\varepsilon}+\sqrt{7x+6}}{\sqrt{7x+6+7\varepsilon}+\sqrt{7x+6}}\\
=&\,\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{(7x+6+7\varepsilon)-(7x+6)}{\varepsilon}\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{7x+6+7\varepsilon}+\sqrt{7x+6}}\\ 
=&\,\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\frac{7\varepsilon}{\varepsilon}\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{7x+6+7\varepsilon}+\sqrt{7x+6}}=\frac{7}{2\sqrt{7x+6}}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 6):

Recall the limit definition of the derivative:

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$$

$\require{cancel}$Now, we're given that $f(x) = \sqrt{7x + 6}$. So,

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{ 7(x+h)+6 }-\sqrt{7x+6}}{h}$$

We multiply the numerator and denominator by the *conjugate* of the *numerator*, then simplify:

$$\begin{align} f'(x) & = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{ 7((x+h)+6 }-\sqrt{7x+6})}{h} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{7(x + h)+ 6} + \sqrt {7x + 6}}{h(\sqrt{7(x + h)+ 6} + \sqrt {7x + 6})}\\ \\ 
& = \lim{h \to 0} \frac{7(x + h) + 6 - (7x + 6)}{h(\sqrt{7(x + h)+ 6} + \sqrt {7x + 6})} \\ \\
& = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{7\cancel{h}}{\cancel{h}(\sqrt{7(x + h)+ 6} + \sqrt {7x + 6})}\\ \\
& = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac 7{\sqrt{7(x+h) + 6} + \sqrt{ 7x + 6}} \\ \\ 
& = \dfrac 7{2(\sqrt {7x + 6})}\end{align}$$

Comment: the only question I have is how did you get the 2 on the bottom

Comment: The denominator evaluates to $\dfrac 7{\sqrt {7 x + 6} + \sqrt {7x + 6}} = \dfrac 7{2\sqrt{7x + 6}}$ as $\bf h\to 0$ when taking the limit at the second to last line. (We are now able to evaluate at $h = 0$!

Comment: @amWhy: Needs a TU! +1

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{Do you know, }f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$$

Here $f(x)=\sqrt{7x+6}\implies f(x+h)=\sqrt{7(x+h)+6}$

$$f(x+h)-f(x)=\sqrt{7(x+h)+6}-\sqrt{7x+6}=\frac{7(x+h)+6-(7x+6)}{\sqrt{7(x+h)+6}+\sqrt{7x+6}}=\frac{7h}{\sqrt{7(x+h)+6}+\sqrt{7x+6}}$$

If $h\ne0,$

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=\frac{7}{\sqrt{7(x+h)+6}+\sqrt{7x+6}}$$

As $h\to0,h\ne0$